# SARIMAX doesn't fit the model

Tags: time-series, arima

I used this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/a-guide-to-time-series-forecasting-with-arima-in-python-3) to find optimal coefficients for my ARIMA model and still it pretty bad (see picture). How can I improve it?

```
sar_m = sarimax.SARIMAX(df_train,
                        trend='n', 
                        order=(2,1,1), 
                        seasonal_order=(2, 1, 1, 24),
                        enforce_stationarity=False,
                        enforce_invertibility=False,
                        simple_differencing=False).fit()
# predict for every hour of the next month
predict_steps = 24*30
forecast = sar_m.forecast(steps=predict_steps)

# plot against real data
plot_forecast(df_test[:predict_steps], forecast, 
              title='SARIMAX - Predicted vs Actual (September 2014)', 
              xlabel='Day in September 2014', 
              ylabel='Number of Pizza Orders')

# calculate RMSE error
rmse(df_test[:predict_steps].numOfOrders, forecast)
```

[image]

Sample data (`df.head()`)

```
date,numOfPizzaOrders
2014-04-01 00:00:00,12
2014-04-01 01:00:00,5
2014-04-01 02:00:00,2
2014-04-01 03:00:00,4
2014-04-01 04:00:00,3
2014-04-01 05:00:00,3
2014-04-01 06:00:00,7
2014-04-01 07:00:00,5
2014-04-01 08:00:00,17
```

Comment: Perhaps you mean that SARIMAX doesn't fit the *data*?

Comment: could you post the graph of your series without the arima estimation? it is hard to see the exact pattern here

Answer (score 0):

You should try to apply differencing.

Maybe even  several times - #1 - seasonal, because when looking at your time series it's obvious there is a seasonality here.

Also, you may need to apply Box-Cox transformation for the dispersion equalization.

After all , apply Dickey-Fuller test together with visual control for to make sure that the time series satisfies stationarity requirement.

Comment: i doubt this series in non-stationary, i think if you remove the trend (which i believe is sinusoidal) the mean and variance remains relatively same